# When is it more appropriate to use a binary model rather than a count model?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

Is there a test or rule of thumb for determining when it is better to use a binary model such as logistic regression vs. a count model such as negative binomial regression?

For example, these data "seem" like a "poor" candidate for a count model and perhaps would be better modeled as a binary model:
count = 0, freq = 10,000,000
count = 1, freq =    700,000
count = 2, freq =        100

These data "seem" like a "better" candidate for a count model:
count = 0, freq = 10,000,000
count = 1, freq =     70,000
count = 2, freq =     25,000
count = 3, freq =     10,000
count = 4, freq =      5,000
count = 5, freq =      1,000
count = 6, freq =        500
count = 7, freq =         50

And these data seem like they are in a grey area between a binary and count model:
count = 0, freq = 10,000,000
count = 1, freq =     70,000
count = 2, freq =      7,000
count = 3, freq =        700
count = 4, freq =        350
count = 5, freq =         90
count = 6, freq =         50
count = 7, freq =          5

I just can't seem to find an answer to this question, but it is also hard (at least for me) to articulate it in a search.

Comment: How would you fit a binary model in your first example?

Comment: Agreed - if those are classes this would end up being multi nominal.

Comment: In the first example I would create a binary variable =  0 if count is zero and 1 if count > 0. Would this be the more appropriate strategy in the third example?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1416241-when-is-it-more-appropriate-to-model-count-data-as-binary-data-i-e-0-if-count-0-and-1-if-count-0).

Answer (score 1):

This sort of comes up in econometrics in the context of limited dependent variable models, where the question is what do the zeros represent.

One setting where this choice is relevant is where there are questions about what economists call the extensive or intensive margin effects. Imagine you were a retailer and you performed an experiment that you thought would make your customers more likely to buy. You might have a treatment where only those who were already buying something added some additional items to their cart (extensive margin). Or you might have a treatment that tips people to go from zero to some purchases (intensive margin from browsing to purchase). Focusing on the binary-ized outcome would be useful in clarifying the intensive margin effect, whereas focusing on the count model would mix up both. Unfortunately, I can't think of an analogy to your aggregated data setting. Perhaps you might have more accidents, but with fewer fatalities each.

Of course, it is possible to have both kind of effects going on, so people will often use hurdle models for count data or two-part models for continuous outcomes.

You also want to be careful to adjust for the size of the counties, since larger counties will have more traffic deaths by virtue of their size. Consider using some measure of at-risk population as a logarithmic offset in a Poisson model.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dimitryi. The extensive vs. intensive margin distinction is a very helpful way to frame the question.